# Show existence and uniqueness of integral equality with neumann-series

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, operator-theory

I want to show that for

$$x(s)-\int_0^12rs\cdot x(r)dr=\sin(\pi s)$$

there exists exactly one solution $x \in C^0([0,1],\mathbb R)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:(Much easier and with neumann-series)**

Write your integral equation as $(I-T)x=c$.

Show now that $(I-T)$ invertible by compution its inverse function. Then the integral equation has an unique solution for every choice of c.

Comment: thanks for this hint! i solved the task!!

Comment: How can I show that $||T||<1??$

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $x$ is a solution of
$$
                x(s)-2s\int_{0}^{1}rx(r)\,dr = \sin(\pi s).
$$
Let $g(r)=r$. In terms of an inner product, $(\cdot,\cdot)$.
$$
                     x(s)=2(x,g)g(s)+\sin(\pi s)
$$
Take the inner-product of the above with $g$. Because $1\ne 2(g,g)$,
$$
               (x,g) = 2(x,g)(g,g)+(\sin(\pi s),g),\\
               (x,g) = \frac{(\sin(\pi s),g)}{1-2(g,g)}.
$$
So the solution is unique if it exists, and it must equal
$$
               x=2g(x,g)+\sin(\pi s)=\frac{2(\sin(\pi s),g)}{1-2(g,g)}g+\sin(\pi s),\\
               x = \frac{2(\sin(\pi s),g)}{1-2(g,g)}g+\sin(\pi s).
$$
Now test this solution:
$$
\begin{align}
x -2g(x,g) & =\left[\frac{2(\sin(\pi s),g)}{1-2(g,g)}g+\sin(\pi s)\right]
   -2g\left(\frac{2(\sin(\pi s),g)}{1-2(g,g)}g+\sin(\pi s),g\right) \\
  & = \left[\frac{2(\sin(\pi s),g)}{1-2(g,g)}(1-2(g,g))\right]g+\sin(\pi s)-2(\sin(\pi s),g)g \\
  & = \sin(\pi s).
\end{align}
$$
So, the proposed solution checks, and it is unique.